# Reason for current being same in a series circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Why current does not decrease after passing through a resistor?

Does the voltage decrease?

Comment: You may like the [electric-hydraulic analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) to get an intuitive understanding of current, voltage, resistance, etc and find the answers by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Current in a wire represents the quantity of electrons that are flowing along the wire in a given time. If the current leaving a resistor were less than the current entering a resistor then this would mean that electrons were "piling up" somehow inside the resistor. This cannot happen (or, at least, cannot happen for more than a short period) - so the current leaving the resistor must be the same as the current entering the resistor. This is a special case of [Kirchhoff's current law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws).

Voltage, on the other hand, represents the work that can be done by the electrons in the wire. Since the electrons do work as they travel through the resistor (and this work heats up the resistor) then the voltage after the resistor is lower than the voltage before the resistor.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this question has been downvoted, you seems to be uninitiated in Physics. It becomes discouraging for newcomers on this site.
This is every fundamental question which you will appreciate after learning about Electrodynamics.

To answer briefly, a circuit is an engineered setup built on the knowledge of Electromagnetic physics to build electrical devices. There are two concepts which abstracts away the whole physics behind the curtains. Voltage and Current.

There is a simple circuit attached below. When the switch is turned, something happens that lightens the bulb. It is said that a flow of tiny charged bodies (popularly called electrons) through the circuit makes it happen. Current is said to be this (flux of) moving charged bodies and Voltage Drop represents the energy spent to do so.

[image]

Each charged body holds some potential to do work. Voltage.

And there are number of them moving in the circuit. Current.

When connected in series they may lose their potential to further do work on next device. Voltage drop. However, The number of them moving remains the same. Current sustains. When they are branched something different happens. Across wires, their numbers get sliced. Current distribution. But their potential to do work stays same. Voltage sustains.

For now, you can believe an army of electrons marching in the circuit. When they are branched, current drops. When they do work, voltage drops.
Read more books. Keep learning.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much